# Changing a custom rule type in sonarqube doesn't work

Tags: sonarqube

I created a custome rule using a template however I can not change the bug category. I select it and press Save but it isn't applied. Any ideas?

[image: Image which shows the open custome rule dialog]

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920703/sonarqube-adds-all-issues-as-code-smell) however we use sonarqube 6.7 and the tag solution doesn't work anymore.

**Update**: I found a workaround: When deleting the issue and selecting the type at creation time it seem to work. So it is probably a bug in sonar...